# Use variable as value in array key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, key-value, braintree

I am using Braintree to do some payment processing and I am sending data from my swift app and I instead of hardcoding the amount, I want it to be dynamic based on which product I select. Is it possible to set the value of a key value pair to be a dynamic variable that is coming into my PHP script?

```
<?php

$price =  htmlentities($_REQUEST["price"]);

$tr_data = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::transactionData(
                array('redirectUrl' => "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH),
                'transaction' => array('amount' => $price, 'type' => 'sale')))
?>
```

Comment: yes, you can pass a variable as key @Eseye

Comment: When i try to use the code I have it keeps saying I have an error but wont tell me what it is...I am passing the value I want from my swift app but It seems to not be recognized by the key value pair amount => $price

Comment: i am not sure but, as type,
 in documentation there is Braintree_Transaction::SALE, try this @Eseye

Comment: I set up some code to display the error:  81502: Amount is required.  I can echo out my price but whe ni try and use it in my key value pair it seems to not be recognized.

Comment: you must be passing a null value, create array outside of Braintree and try print_r($arr); @Eseye

Comment: hmm you are correct.  my swift function that sends the post data is working.  Im not sure whats going on.  But thank you for helping me go in the right direction

Comment: You are welcome @Eseye